# How to use current Drive name in WritePrivateProfileString()

Tags: c++, winapi

How would i find the current drive name where my executable file is running?

I want to use WritePrivateProfileString() for saving a string in .ini file. I want to make the file name to be generic, as the hardcoding the full path or drive name is not a good idea.

Can anyone please tell me how to retrieve the current drive name to use in this API.

I am using this API something like this:-

```
WritePrivateProfileString(_T("device"), _T("i2c_address"), temp, _T("D:\log.ini"));
```

I don't want to hardcode D over here please let me know how can I make this generic.

Comment: Don't save in the root directory of *any* drive. The function you want is [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx), with a `KNOWNFOLDERID` of `FOLDERID_ProgramData`. That will give you the path of the Application Data folder, where you should be storing application data like INI files. Search SO for questions about how to use this, there have been many.

Comment: WritePrivateProfileString(_T("device"), _T("i2c_address"), temp, _T("D:\log.ini"));
does not save the INI file in the root directory, this way the INI file gets store in the directory of "D" drive where my application executable is present. I only want to know how can I get this first letter from the application path

Comment: I'm relatively sure that's *not* true. If you call the function with `D:\log.ini` as the path, it will save in `D:\log.ini` (the root of drive D:), not the application's directory. However, if you pass a relative path (like `log.ini`), it will redirect to the registry. You need an absolute path, like the one obtained using `GetModuleFileName`. But then you'll need to trim the EXE name off of it, using something like `PathRemoveFileSpec`. Then you'll use `PathAppend` to concatenate that directory path with your file name, `log.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get the full absolute path of the running module using [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for the active module you use:

```
GetModuleFileName(NULL,Buffer,BufferLength);
```

Comment: Thank you this works great.
But Can you please tell me how should now I use this buffer[0] in place of "D" in my code?
buffer is LPWSTR type and in the API i need to pass a LPCTSTR value?

Comment: use std::wstring or std::basic_string<TCHAR>

Comment: i.e. LPWSTR is a typedef of WCHAR*, LPCTSTR is a typedef of TCHAR const*, TCHAR is a typedef of either CHAR or WCHAR depending upon if you are doing a unicode build.  If GetModuleFileName compiled with LPWSTR then you are building unicode.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. It tells how to get the path to the application's executable file, but it doesn't tell how to strip the executable file name and extension to get just the path (`PathRemoveFileSpec`), or how to append that to the desired INI file name (`PathAppend`).